# Куда копать, чтобы сделать обработчик входящих писем(запросов)?

Tags: node.js

Имеется такая проблема: нужно сделать, чтобы письма(сообщения/запросы, не знаю как верно, но приходить они будут в виде электронного письма), приходящие по одному и тому же шаблону преобразовывались в некоторый вид данных, например строка и изображение. И я на своей стороне либо принимаю их, либо отклоняю. Ну, в случае приёма будет происходить какое-то действие, в ином случае просто удаляться. Я не уверен, что правильно выразил то, что хочу сделать, но надеюсь подскажете, в какую сторону мне копать, что изучать для того чтобы реализовать такой функционал.
Предположительно буду использовать nodejs.. Но если есть какие-то другие варианты, то в целом проблем нет.

Comment: Вы хотите сделать smtp сервер?

Comment: Насколько я понял smpt сервер только отправляет/получает письма и это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Или же я могу как-то это использовать? Ну, приведу пример. Приходит мне на почту письмо вида:
Привет, вот это $something
*тут картинка*


И мне нужно получить это картинку и этот $something

Comment: @UserTest013 правильно понимаю, что мне нужно смотреть в сторону imap?

Comment: Попробуйте готовое решение, возможно это то что вам нужно https://nodemailer.com/extras/smtp-server/ . Также вам надо будет использовать mailparser из того же комплекта https://nodemailer.com/extras/mailparser/

Comment: @UserTest013 Спасибо! При беглом осмотре выглядит как то что нужно :) Всё-таки знание терминов и как поставить правильно вопрос важно..